# SQL Exception Login failed for user "service account Name"

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-4.0

I am using a serviceaccount util.sql.TestApp on a database I created.

When I reach `command.Connection.Open();` I am getting the SQL Exception Login failed for util.sql.TestApp

This what I have in my web.config

```
<add name="DBTest" connectionString="Server=Data.companyname.com; Database=TestApp; User Id=util.sql.TestApp; password=PWD" providerName=""/>
```

I opened the database and checked the serviceaccount. It does have connect previlages. I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Is the service account a windows account or a SQL account? If it is the former, you'll need a different connection string --`Server=Data.companyname.com; Database=TestApp;Trusted_Connection=true` --  and also to setup the application pool to run as the service account [which might already be done and perhaps why they told you to use the service account].

Comment: It is a service account. Util.sql.AppName

Comment: Of course it is a service account -- but how was the user created? Is it a SQL server principle? Or a windows principle?

Answer (score 0):

Did you map the user to the `TestApp` database (not just SQL Server) with Connect permissions?

To check this, in object explorer go to the `Security` folder in the root, and expand `Logins`. Right-click the user account and click `Properties`. Under `User Mapping`, make sure the user is mapped to `TestApp`. Once the user is mapped to `TestApp`, you can go into the properties of `TestApp` to configure permissions for the database.

Secondly, have you tried giving the account `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, and `DELETE` permissions too.

Comment: The service account doesn't need CRUD access to be able to login to the database.

Comment: Yes I did tried giving the select, update , delete permissions. It didn't work. what do you mean by mapping user to the testapp database?

The user is a service account I created to access that specific database.

Answer (score 0):

Did you map the user to the appropriate DB role? You should try deleting the user under the DB's Security > Users, and then remap a local db user via Security > Logins to the DB in question. From there you will have to right click the user > properties > user mapping, then select your DB using checkbox in top list, then select a role at the bottom of that window and click save. The key is to make sure you give it the appropriate access level in the bottom of the User Mapping screen. This should take care of any permission issues.

Comment: Yes I added the util.sql.testapp to my .net folder. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Curious are you using IIS7 and ASP.Net 4?  Try going to the Event Viewer and pulling the ASP.Net "Warning" for the Web Events.  In the General tab you can find the Exception information.  Once you have this you might be able to pin point where the issue is the stack trace.  If you do not mind post it here as well.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: I am using .net 4.0 (I am developing it locally). see my stack trace

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnection owningObject, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, TimeoutTimer timeout)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(SqlConnection owningObject, TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, String newPassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SqlConnection owningObject, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)

Comment: at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)

Comment: at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
 at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at _Default.btnSubmit_OnClick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in

Comment: C:\Users\UserName\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestAPP\TestAPP\Default.aspx.cs:line 188